# help with really simple csv importer

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, csv

( sorry for the title, but i dont know how to explain this as a title ^^ ).

I'm using [really simple csv importer](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-csv-importer/) to bulk import data in my site, using Advanced custom fields.

So i need to import some data as serialized data. So i used the hook "really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter" as show in docs.

But i have an issue, the hook just explain how to filter serialized data, but not how to keep normal data. So it works well with my 2 serialized columns, and delete all the other columns.

how can i custom my hooks to keep other columns active ?

my columns :

post_type   post_title  contact_city    seo_h1  marche_tel  rank_math_title marche_periode  marche_h_debut  marche_h_fin    marche_www  marche_latitude marche_longitude    marche_maps marche_dpt  type_un type_deux   type_trois  jour_un jour_deux   jour_trois  jour_quatre jour_cinq   jour_six    jour_sept

my hook :

```
function really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter( $meta, $post, $is_update ) {
    $meta_array = array();

    $metas = [
        'marche_jours' => ['jour_un', 'jour_deux', 'jour_trois', 'jour_quatre', 'jour_cinq', 'jour_six', 'jour_sept'],
        'marche_type' => ['type_un', 'type_deux', 'type_trois'],
    ];

    foreach ($metas as $metaKey => $metaFields) {
        foreach ($metaFields as $field) {
            if (isset($meta[$field])) {
                $meta_array[$metaKey][] = $meta[$field];
            }
        }
    }

    return $meta_array;
}
add_filter( 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta', 'really_simple_csv_importer_save_meta_filter', 10, 3 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answear is available here with explaination (french).
https://www.wpnuls.fr/import-csv-de-champs-acf-avec-really-simple-csv-importer-740.html